# FileNotFoundException SQLite database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-listview

I am trying to load data from existing SQlite database, but It throws "FileNotFoundException" error

> "W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cc_recipes.db"

So My application displays recipes name and image in a listview.

I already created this application using Eclipse the last time, and it worked very good but when I changed it using Android Studio. I can't just find what causes the error

I did find some solutions here, but It's not working too

Can any one help me, please!

This is my code:

```
package com.mypackage.example;

import java.io.File; import java.io.FileOutputStream; import java.io.IOException; import java.io.InputStream; import java.io.OutputStream; import java.util.ArrayList; import android.content.Context; import android.database.Cursor; import android.database.SQLException; import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException; import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static String DB_PATH = "";

    private final static String DB_NAME = "cc_recipes.db";
    public final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;

    private Context mContext;

    private final String TABLE_NAME = "recettes";
    private final String ID = "id";
    private final String RECIPE_NAME = "title";
    private final String IMAGE_PREVIEW = "image_preview";
    private final String INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
    private final String DIRECTIONS = "preparation";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            //E:\new folders\My study\Projet Ouafae Kandoussi\YammyCook\app\src\main\assets\databases\cc_recipes.db
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;
        Log.i("msg","Here my msg: "+DB_PATH);
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
            // check if we need to upgrade
            openDataBase();
            int cVersion = db.getVersion();
            if(cVersion != 2){
                onUpgrade(db, db.getVersion(), 2);}
            close();
        } else {
            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }
    private void deleteDataBase(){
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

        dbFile.delete();
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    /** this code is used to get all data from database */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllData(String RecipeNameKeyword){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        Cursor cursor = null;

        if(RecipeNameKeyword.equals("")){
            try{
                cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[]{ID, RECIPE_NAME, IMAGE_PREVIEW},
                        null, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                    do{
                        ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                        dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));

                        dataArrays.add(dataList);
                    }

                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
                Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            try{
                cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[]{ID, RECIPE_NAME, IMAGE_PREVIEW},
                        RECIPE_NAME +" LIKE '%"+RecipeNameKeyword+"%'",
                        null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                    do{
                        ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                        dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));

                        dataArrays.add(dataList);
                    }

                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
                Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dataArrays;
    }

//  public ArrayList<Object> getRandomData(){ //        ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>(); //        Cursor cursor; //       try{ // //          cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+RECIPE_NAME+","+ IMAGE_PREVIEW+", "+ INGREDIENTS+","+ DIRECTIONS+" FROM"+TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null); // //           cursor.moveToFirst(); // //         if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){ //              do{ //                  rowArray.add(cursor.getString(0)); //                   rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1)); //                   rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2)); //                   rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3)); //               } //                while (cursor.moveToNext()); //         } // //         cursor.close(); //      } //        catch (SQLException e) //       { //            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString()); //         e.printStackTrace(); //     } // // //      return rowArray; //     }

    /** this code is used to get data from database base on id value */
    public ArrayList<Object> getDetail(long id){

        ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Cursor cursor;

        try{
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[] {RECIPE_NAME, IMAGE_PREVIEW, INGREDIENTS, DIRECTIONS},
                    ID + "=" + id,
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                do{
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3));
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rowArray;
    } }
```

ListRecipesFragment class:

```
package com.mypackage.example;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ListRecipesFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText edtSearch;
    ListView listRecipes;

    String RecipeNameKeyword = "";

    static DBHelper dbhelper;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data;
    ListAdapter la;

    static int[] id;
    static String[] RecipeName;
    static String[] Preview;
    static String[] CookTime;


    /** This class is used to create custom listview */
    static class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context ctx;

        public ListAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            ctx = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return RecipeName.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtRecipeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRecipeName);
                holder.txtReadyIn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtReadyIn);
                holder.imgPreview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.txtRecipeName.setText(RecipeName[position]);
            int imagePreview = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(Preview[position], "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
            holder.imgPreview.setImageResource(imagePreview);


            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtRecipeName, txtReadyIn;
            ImageView imgPreview;
        }

    }


    public ListRecipesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_recipes, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        dbhelper = new DBHelper(getView().getContext());
        la = new ListAdapter(getView().getContext());
        listRecipes = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listRecipes);

        /**
         * when this app's installed at the first time, code below will
         * copy database stored in assets to
         * /data/data/com.recipes.app/databases/
         */
        try {
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        /** then, the database will be open to use */
        try{
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
        new getDataTask().execute();


        listRecipes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                /**
                 * when one of item in the list is clicked, this app will access
                 * RecipeDetail.class. it also send id value to that class
                 */
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipeDetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id_for_detail", id[position]);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    /** this class is used to handle thread */
    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getDataFromDatabase(RecipeNameKeyword);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
            if(id.length > 0){
                listRecipes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                listRecipes.setAdapter(la);
            }else{
                //txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }
            dbhelper.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * this code is used to get data from database and store them
     * to array attributes
     */
    public void getDataFromDatabase(String RecipeNameKeyword){
        data = dbhelper.getAllData(RecipeNameKeyword);

        id = new int[data.size()];
        RecipeName = new String[data.size()];
        Preview = new String[data.size()];

        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(i);

            id[i] = Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString());
            RecipeName[i] = row.get(1).toString();
            Preview[i] = row.get(2).toString().trim();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
    {
        // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `listRecipes.xml` have to do with a database path and/or connection?  why include that in the code.  What about `row.xml`?  Only share code this is likely relevant to the immediate problem.  Please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Be more specific about the error: What line of code was it for?  What did you do to debug this problem?  It is not sufficient to just say that you found solutions but they didn't work.  What "solutions" and what did you try?  The code shows that you output `DB_PATH` to a log, so did you check the log and confirm the path is correct?  Did you actually go to the path and confirm the file exists where you think it does?  You also call a `copydata()` function in multiple places, so have you traced that code and ensured it is working properly?  The solution is probably just old fashioned debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that executive file path directory contain the "cc_recipes.db" file.

Comment: It contains the database file